# How to restart file operations (file explorer) in the MATE desktop?

Tags: mate-desktop, file-manager

I was emptying the trash on my machine (Debian 8 Jessie with the MATE desktop) and then did some other operation. Long story short, the whole file explorer is frozen. I can't seem to find anything in `htop` because I don't know what the file explorer's process is called. How can I restart the file explorer only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The process is called `caja`.

I didn't find out until after I `sudo apt-get install gnome-system-monitor` and saw the little file cabinet icon next to a process called `caja`. Killing that worked. Now I know the process is called `caja` and can of course also see it in `htop` now after a restart.

Answer (score 3):

If the explorer can get itself out by itself:

```
caja --quit
nautilus --quit
```

the desktop will restart automatically.